# Bash Script CURL Request a File Getting Failed to open/read local data from file/application

Tags: bash, curl

I have a bash script that loops through all files in a directory and makes a curl request to some URL

```
for FILE in ./files/*;
    do  
        echo "Making a request..."
        echo $FILE

        curl --location --request POST "${URL}" \
        --form 'file=@"${FILE}"' \

        sleep 100
    done

echo "done!"
```

The curl request was copied from postman so I'm confident that it works.

When I run the script, I get the following

```
Making a request...
./files/split1.csv
curl: (26) Failed to open/read local data from file/application
```

The issue I'm getting is how to handle string interpolation here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close, just remove the single quotes to get the string interpolation to work.

```
curl --location --request POST "${URL}" \
--form file=@"${FILE}" \
```